# Using emacs for OpenGL

Tags: opengl, emacs, ide

Can anybody tell me how to compile the opengl code in **emacs** just like we do in **visual studio**?
What we should do you link the library in **emacs** to run opengl code in emacs? Is it even possible? I've seen the internet that you can use **emacs** as you IDE although it is a text editor.

Comment: Are you asking how to compile and run an OpenGL application without leaving Emacs?

Comment: No I wanted to compile opengl file from shell by doing linking in cmd only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs is just an editor. It doesn't give a iota about *what* you're writing in it. Sure you can loads a gazillion macros in it, and somewhere someone might have even created a Emacs Lisp implementation of OpenGL. But that's not relevant for this question.

**What editor you use is completely irrelevent to programming OpenGL!**

I think what you're really interested in is, how to write Makefiles or equivalent for other build systems.

---

You want to compile OpenGL code? Great! To do so in C or C++ include the OpenGL headers in your source code, i.e.

```
#if defined(__APPLE__)
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#else
#include <GL/gl.h>
#endif
```

For any other language use the appropriate bindings.

Then add the OpenGL to your linker:

For Windows:

- Visual C++: Add `opengl32.lib` to the list of extra libraries
- MinGW / GCC / Clang: Add `-lopengl32` to the linker stage

For Linux:

- If linking for GLvnd (recommended): Add `-lOpenGL` to the linker stage
- If not using GLvnd: Add `-lGL` to the linker stage

For macOS: Add `-framework OpenGL` to the compiler and linker stages.